# Compartir por clases heredadas un thread que actualiza una variable estática de la clase padre

Tags: java, hilos, herencia

Estoy realizando un proyecto que se encarga de leer las cotizaciones de eventos en diferentes webs.
Para cada web creo una clase que se encarga de leer los datos de esa web y hereda de una clase padre.

Deseo que todas las clases heredadas de esa clase padre compartan un campo estático que contenga un calendario de eventos. Ese calendario de eventos quiero que se actualice cada minuto mediante un thread  y aquí es donde me surgen las dudas.

¿Ese thread puede ser creado por la primera clase hija instanciada, dejando que actualice la variable estática de listado de eventos? ¿para hacer algo así debería declarar ese thread como un campo estático en la clase padre para que sólo se instancie si al instanciar la primera clase hija?

La idea sería una estructura similar a esta:

```
    public abstract class GenericCrawler extends Thread {

        public static CalendarThread  calThread;
        public static List<Eventos>  eventosCalendario;

    }

    public class CrawlerA extends GenericCrawler {
        //itera con la lista eventosCalendario un bucle que se repite de forma perpetua para actualizar los precios en todo momento
    }

    public class CrawlerB extends GenericCrawler {
       //itera con la lista eventosCalendario un bucle que se repite de forma perpetua para actualizar los precios en todo momento
    }

    public class CalendarThread extends Thread{
    //Crea la lista de eventos y los actualiza cada minuto añadiendo o eliminando eventos
}
```

Comment: La actualización del Calendario es independiente de las clases que leen las cotizaciones de eventos? O son esas clases que actualizan el Calendario?

Comment: La actualización del calendario en se sentido es independiente de las otras clases. La clase calendario es la única que puede añadir o eliminar eventos, pero los eventos que contiene dicha clase son usados por el resto de clases para actualizar los precios de dichos eventos.

Comment: En ese caso el Calendario debería crear su propio Thread para sus actualizaciones al momento de instancirse. Igualmente para entender bien donde está lo que te genera la duda, necesitarias agregar mas detalles sobre la arquitectura. El código relevante por ejemplo.

Comment: He editado mi pregunta agregando un esquema de como pienso que podría ser la arquitectura, aunque no se si es correcto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que el problema mas grande que vas a tener es con la lista de eventos y el acceso concurrente del calendario que actualiza los eventos y de los crawlers que seguramente la tiene que recorrer para extraer información. Una forma de encarar este punto es sincronizando el acceso a la lista. Otra podría ser usar `CopyOnWriteArrayList` que es una versión de `ArrayList` que es Thread safe.

Mirándo el sistema que querés armar desde uan perspectiva más amplia me parece que no necesitás métodos ni atributos estáticos.

Se podría armar de esta forma:

```
public class App{

    private Calendario calendario;
    private CrawlerA crawlerA;
    private CrawlerB crawlerB;

    public static void main(String [] args){
        App app = new App();
        app.start();
    }

    public void start(){
        Calendario calendario = new Calendario();
        Thread threadCalendario  =  new Thread(calendario);
        thredCalendario.start();

        CrawlerA crawlerA = new CrawlerA(calendario);
        CrawlerB crawlerB = new CrawlerB(calendario);

        Thread tca = new Thread(crawlerA).start();
        Thread tcb = new Thread(crawlerB).start();
    }

}
```

Luego el calendario actualiza sus eventos y provee el o los métodos para entregar información a los crawlers.
El acceso a la lista se sincroniza dado que la actualización puede caer cuando el thread de un crawler está ejecutando getXdeEvento() así que hacemos esperar a uno u a otro thread.
X viene a ser cualquier cosa que el crawler necesite de la lista.
Y el método getXdeEvento(), se llama sobre el calendario, y devuelve ese X.

```
private class Calendario implements Runnable{
    private static final long MILLIS_ENTRE_ACTUALIZACION = 60 * 1000; // 1 minuto

    private boolean end = false;
    private List<Eventos>  eventos = new ArrayList<>();

    public void run(){
        while(!end){
            sychronized(eventos){
                //Actualizar eventos
            }
            try{
                Thread.sleep(MILLIS_ENTRE_ACTUALIZACION);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                //Manejar la excepción.
            }
        }
    }

    // Método para buscar infomración X en el calendario
    public X getXdeEvento(int idEvento){
        X rtn = null;
        synchronized(eventos){
            for(Evento evento : eventos){
                if(evento.getId() == idEvento){
                    rtn.setInfoDelEvento(evento.getInfoDelEvento());
                }
            }
        }
        return rtn;
    }

    public void stop(){
        this.end = true;
    }
}
```

Y Los crawlers (A y B serían iguales en este nivel de abstracción, así que pongo el  código que va para los dos).
Los crawlers corren un loop donde buscan algo del calendario, hacen algo con eso, y luego duermen un rato.

```
public class CrawlerA implements Runnable{
    private static final long MILLIS_ENTRE_ACTUALIZACION = 2 * 60 * 1000; // 2 minutos
    Calendar calendario;

    private boolean end = false;

    public CrawlerA(Calendario calendario){
        this.calendario = calendario;
    }

    public void run(){
        while(!end){
            X xDeEvento = calendario.getXdeEvento();

            // Hacer algo con X

            try{
                Thread.sleep(MILLIS_ENTRE_ACTUALIZACION);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                //Manejar la excepción.
            }
        }

    }

    public void stop(){
        this.end = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Dentro de esta arquitectura, ¿sería posible añadir a la clase App el campo CopyOnWriteArrayList de eventos? Campo que sería actualizado en cuanto a los eventos existentes por la clase Calendario(añade y elimina eventos) y en cuanto otros campos de datos que contiene la clase Eventos se actualizaría por las clases Crawler con lo cual también crearía un campo CopyOnWriteArrayList de eventos con referencia a la lista de eventos que crea la clase Calendario.

Comment: Por lo que comentas me parece que no te va a servir el CopyOnWriteArrayList. Esa case quita el tema de sincronizar el acceso al arraylist (pagando un costo de performance), pero no te va a servir para la actualización de los datos de los eventos por parte de los diferentes crawlers. En mi respuesta hay un metodo para obtener un dato X de los eventos. De la misma manera podes hacer métodos que los crawlers llamen sobre el calendario para modificar datos de los eventos (siempre sincronizando el acceso a la lista).

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de la arquitectura que expones me surge una duda.

En las clases Crawler dentro de su bucle perpetuo deben llamar a métodos del propio Crawler que necesita tener una lista de eventos sobre la que iterar y que posteriormente actualizará datos del evento si es que no ha sido eliminado por la clase Calendar.
Para evitar problemas de concurrencia al iterar había pensado que la clase Crawler tenga un campo privado lista de Eventos que se actualice llamando a la clase Calendar cada iteración del bucle y que una vez haga las operaciones pertinentes con cada evento vuelva a llamar a la clase Calendar para actualizar los datos del evento

```
public class CrawlerA implements Runnable{
    private static final long MILLIS_ENTRE_ACTUALIZACION = 2 * 60 * 1000; // 2 minutos
    Calendar calendario;
    private List<Evento> listaPrivadaEventos;
    private boolean end = false;

    public CrawlerA(Calendario calendario){
        this.calendario = calendario;
    }

    public void run(){
        while(!end){

            listaPrivadaEventos = calendario.getListaEventos();
            /*llama a métodos de este crawler que iteran sobre listaPrivadaEventos
            actualizan datos de cada evento contenido en esa listaPrivadaEventos
            envia esa listaPrivadaEventos a calendario para que este modifique los 
            de la lista original*/
            calendario.actualizarDatosListaEventos(listaPrivadaEventos);



            try{
                Thread.sleep(MILLIS_ENTRE_ACTUALIZACION);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                //Manejar la excepción.
            }
        }

    }

    public void stop(){
        this.end = true;
    }
}
```